# ASP .NET Check if another user has permission on folder or file

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I'm developing a SharePoint 2010 web part that shows links to files and folders inside our network (network share).

Application pool user has access to all of the folders.

How can I check if the current logged Active Directory user has permission to the folder in order to eventually remove some of those links?

Maybe with impersonation?